# Eclipse Method 'insert' could not be resolved with GCC 4.9.1

Tags: c++, eclipse

i installed the new gcc 4.9.1 now i have a lot of problems with my c++ indexer in eclipse. He can't resolve the standard types.

I use Eclipse Juno or Luna. Do you have any ideas what i have to change that the indexer can solve my types?

Comment: `sed -i 's|/usr/lib/gcc/$ARCH/$OLD_VERSION|/usr/lib/gcc/$ARCH/$NEW_VERSION|g' $PROJECTPATH/.project` has served me well if I remember correctly. Replace the variables and path to your gcc as appropriate. You may also want to do that to eclipse's configuration files if they point to old paths.

Comment: i used a clean workspace and used cmake to build my eclipse project so it should work or?

Comment: How you build the project does not affect eclipse's static analyzer / indexer. Compiling with cmake should work even if indexer doesn't find standard headers.

Comment: i deactivated code analysis and now it runs well. Have no idea why